# Sharepoint Workflow does not run after item has been created

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint discussion board where users can post any issues. In this board I created a workflow which runs after an item has been created (I allow manually starting the workflow after an create item from email message). The workflow runs fine but in some cases (around 1 of 50) the workflow does not run at all. 
There is no message about any errors, the workflow just does not run. When I try to run the workflow manually everything work correctly.

I'v tried looking in: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\ but there are no items and I don't have any idea what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you running the standard SharePoint Designer workflow or are you using a 3rd party tool? Try adding "log to History" after each step to see where your workflow stops working. You should be able to see why the Workflow stopped on the workflow page for that item.

Comment: im running Sharepoint Designer workflow. I have many log to history steps. But the workflow is in this cases not runned at all. In the workflow log of concret item is nothing, no messages about the workflow, no history.

Comment: Have you full patchs on Sharepoint 2010 ? Look into Event Viewer, the service who launch the workflow is the **owstimer.exe** check if this service is configure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not running old workflows. You can do a Powershell monitoring, case does not run powershell run the workflow. The reason for this problem is to have very workflow running at the same time.